# Clarification for a class of Turing machine problems

Tags: turing-machines

So say I have a task like this:

> Construct a Turing machine transforming the word u to the word v byt
>   removing all the sequences of form "ba" from the word u. Input
>   alphabet = {a,b,c}.
>
> Example: for IN cabbaacba, OUT cac.

And my problem always is: can I leave blank characters in place of "ba" sequences in tasks like this so that in the end, I have something like $ca \Phi \Phi \Phi \Phi c \Phi \Phi$ on the tape or do I have to work on the tape in such a way that I end up with, for example "cac", written consecutively, without blanks?

Comment: The specification does not say that you can have spaces between the symbols in the output word. Is the blank character even in the output language?

Comment: I don't know, that's all the spec I have. If it doesn't explicitly state the output language, couldn't I just create my own by using the input one + blank symbol?

Comment: But that doesn't seem to answer the question. The question does not mention replacing "ba" by spaces.

Comment: I see. So it seems in such tasks I'd just have to find a way to leave only the desired characters. Thank you, then! :)

Comment: @Dave Write it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question does not mention replacing "ba" by spaces.     It does not say that you can have spaces between the symbols in the output word. Is the blank character even in the output language?

Comment: Also: how it output of a Turing machine defined here? Can make a difference.